# how to read barcode from usb barcode_device

Tags: java, barcode-scanner

is there a class or library that I can use to read barcode from usb barcode device like excel ??

I want when click on an item that holds a barcode to save that code in an array or print it in text field

is there a listener like keylistener or mouselistener ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no. You'd have to check the documentation of your scanner.

However, most barcode scanners are configured out of the box (or can be configured by scanning various barcodes in the manual that came with the scanner) to operate as a keyboard. Barcodes just contain text strings. A barcode scanner in keyboard mode acts like a keyboard: It 'types in' the scanned code and hits enter.

In java you can just make a swing form or web form or what have you, and instruct the user: Start up our app / open our site, make sure it's frontmost and don't mess with the focus (which should be in some JTextField or html `<textarea>`), then just detect enter presses. This has the advantage that users can also manually type in a code and hit enter - your software won't even be able to tell the difference.

Comment: so If I created a frame and added a textfield , the barcode scanner will print code in it ?
@rzwitserloot

Comment: If you configure the barcode scanner in keyboard mode? Yeah. Just try it right now. Open notepad or textedit or whatever, and scan something. You should see the scanned code on a line, exactly as if you had typed in by hand and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

copy this code in your index.html
but don't split  the JavaScript if you split them you will never working

```html
html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Barcode Scanner</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Simple Barcode Scanner</h1>
        <strong>Last scanned barcode: </strong>
        <div id="last-barcode"></div>
        <script >
               var barcode = '';
               var interval;
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(evt) {
        if (interval)
            clearInterval(interval);
        if (evt.code == 'Enter') {
            if (barcode)
                handleBarcode(barcode);
            barcode = '';
            return;
        }
        if (evt.key != 'Shift')
            barcode += evt.key;
            interval = setInterval(() => barcode = '', 20);
    });

function handleBarcode(scanned_barcode) {
      document.querySelector('#last-barcode').innerHTML = scanned_barcode;
}
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

id you wont to **handle** the barcode  you get back  you can handle it
inside of methode **handleBarcode()**